# Y position of an Ascii art doesn't change whereas, X position does

Tags: python-3.x, list, position, ascii-art

I have this code here:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from colorama import init
init()

path = os.getcwd()
frame_logo = []
frame_data = []
frame_name = ["frame1.txt", "frame2.txt", "frame3.txt", "frame4.txt"]

for i in frame_name:
    fullPath = "{}\\assets\\".format(path)
    with open(fullPath + str(i), "r+") as f:
        readData = f.read()
        frame_data.append(readData)
with open(fullPath + "ldr_logo.txt", "r+") as f:
    readData = f.read()
    frame_logo.append(readData)

def printPos(x, y, text_to_print):
     sys.stdout.write("\x1b[%d;%df%s" % (x, y, text_to_print))
     sys.stdout.flush()

def Animation():
    print(" ")
    printPos(1, 20, frame_data[0])
...
```

So, each file in `frame_name` list contains Ascii art and, the file content is saved in `frame_data` (so, `frame_data[0]` contains Ascii art of `frame1.txt` etc...). When I try to use the `printPos` function (to print at a specific position) against a simple string ("foo" for example) it works but, when I try to do it against an Ascii art (`frame_data[0]` for example) only the X position moves and the Y stays the same.

I tried `printPos(1, 20, str(frame_data[0]))` and it gives the same output and even made another simple "foo" string in a list to test (because I suspected lists when I tried to print the Ascii art) to `printPos` it and it worked. I don't know why the Y pos doesn't change with the Ascii art, any clue? And thanks!